# How to write a style for a control that changes width of another control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there any way to write a `Style` for a control that changes width of another control?

```
<Style x:Key="SubMenuStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightCyan"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Menu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="0" Duration="0:0:.5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This code leads to error:

> TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter

I know I can write codes below and it works:

```
<Label Name="Owners" Margin="0,1,0,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="SubMenuClicked" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuStyle}">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Menu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="0" Duration="0:0:.5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

But since I use this trigger in multiple labels I want to write it in a style once.

This is my code to define controls:

```
<Border Name="Menu" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" Background="LightCyan">
    <StackPanel Name="MenuPanel">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonsStyle}">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ListsMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="86" Duration="0:0:.6"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>

        <StackPanel Name="ListsMenu" Height="0">
            <Label Name="Owners" Margin="0,1,0,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="SubMenuClicked" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuStyle}"/>
            <Label Name="Contacts" MouseLeftButtonDown="SubMenuClicked" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuStyle}"/>
            <Label Name="Groups" MouseLeftButtonDown="SubMenuClicked" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Scenario: There is a border, It's default width is zero, It will raise to 165 in another trigger which works fine, I want to animate it to zero again when labels are clicked, but I can not access the width of that border in lables style

Comment: In the `Style` of triggers can not use objects with `TargetName`, such animation. To do this, they are placed in triggers template. ([Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86f28ade-84ad-4470-bb17-f32402c34a6f/problem-using-sourcename-in-property-trigger-and-targetname-in-setter)). As an alternative, you can use the `DataTemplate`, because he does have a namescope. Simply place these objects within a `DataTemplate`. [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18303/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-4-Data-templates-and-tri) of using `DataTemplate`.

Comment: A datatemplate?! or a controltemplate? I took a look at links, but it is about a class called river, while I don't have such data classes, I just have a border and some buttons and labels.
but thanks for your answer, I'll take a look at controltemplates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim that you use triggers in multiple labels so you can define trigger one time like this

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="animation">
             <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ListsMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="86" Duration="0:0:.6"/>
        </Storyboard>
```

and later when you need you can call it

```
 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource animation}"/> 
            </EventTrigger>
```

But I'm a bit confused what you meant to acquire. 
You cannot get access in style since style does not have a namescope, as it was said. If it changes label's width you could do this in style like this

```
  <Style x:Key="style_button" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="300" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

but it invokes by StoryBoard.TargetName to another object.

Comment: There is a border, It's default width is zero, It will raise to 165 in another trigger which works fine, I want to animate it to zero again when labels are clicked, but I can not access the width of that border in lables style.
however, your current answer seems good, at least it prevents repeating code.

Comment: I tried it, works fine, but does that mean that there is no way to do it in a style? or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
     <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard>
               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=Menu}"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="0" Duration="0:0:.5"/>
           </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
```

TargetName is only valid inside Templates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not work, it throw an exception that happens when Width is not set to a value and it's Nan, but I set Width to zero!

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Cannot animate the 'Width' property on a 'System.Windows.Controls.Label' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'. For details see the inner exception.
--------------------------------------
Exception: Thrown: ",System.Widow.Media.DoubleAnimation' cannot use default value of 'NaN'"(System.InvalidOperationException)

Comment: @SamanHakimzadehAbyaneh why does it refer to your Label as "Menu" ?

Comment: I don't refer to labels! The trigger must change the width of the border which is called Menu to zero, It's default value is zero, but it will change to 165 in another trigger which works fine, and then after I click on labels I expect it to change to zero again